# In VS Code , Can I Auto-Complete function parameters for PHP?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

I changed my editor from Sublime to VS Code.

I installed several Extensions like PHP IntelliSense , PHP Intelephense.
But Auto completion won't complete parameters in a bracket of a function.

---

#### NOW (VS CODE)

Here is a gif in which function name is auto completed but parameters for the funciton are just suggested and not Auto completed.

[image]

---

#### Ideal Behavior (PHP Snippets add on in Sublime 3)

Below is what I want.
In sublime , PHP snippets add on can auto complete parameters for the function.
This really helped me a lot , because I could just double click the placeholder parameters and replace them with values or variables which I wanna use.

[image]

Does anyone know better Extension or has any idea to get the same behavior as this in VS code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use user snippet.  Its `Settings` > `User Snippets` > `New Global Snippet File`
[image]

Here, you can add your snippet in JSON format

```
    "array_column": {
        "scope": "php",
        "prefix": "array_column",
        "body": [
            "array_column(${1:array}, ${2:column_key}, ${3:index_key})",
        ],
        "description": "array_column(array, column_key, index_key) - Return the values from a single column in the input array"
    }
```

Now, as you type `array_column` in a PHP file, you will see your snippet there. You can use the Keyboard key `TAB` to jump to the next parameter of array_column.

PS: I'm answering this old question if someone gets help from this.